# Spotfire IF Statement in Custom Expression

Tags: if-statement, formula, spotfire

`If(Len([case_SPEC]> 0),[case_SPEC],[case_type])`

When I tried above formula I receive an error

> '>' as invalid operator

Could someone help in fixing this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
If(Len([THROUGHPUT_SPEC]) > 0,[THROUGHPUT_SPEC],[SUB_TYPE])
```

You omitted the closing bracket in `Len([THROUGHPUT_SPEC])`

Comment: Be sure to format your expressions with the CODE button or use ` at the beginning and end of your statements for readability.